# Why k8s pod can't find key in ConfigMap?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm having an issue with a Kubernetes pod that uses a ConfigMap. My pod fails to start, with the following error:

`Warning  Failed          10s (x7 over 2m16s)  kubelet, docker-desktop  Error: Couldn't find key URL in ConfigMap default/env-config`

I created my ConfigMap as follows:

`kubectl create configmap env-config --from-file env-config.yaml`

This is my ConfigMap:

```
NAME         DATA   AGE
env-config   1      5m38s
Nates-MacBook-Pro:k8s natereed$ kubectl describe configmap env-config
Name:         env-config
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Data
====
env-config.yaml:
----
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
data:
  AWS_BUCKET: mybucket
  AWS_PROFILE: dev
  AWS_REGION: us-east-2
  JWT_SECRET: foo
  POSTGRESS_DB: <mydb>
  POSTGRESS_HOST: <my host>
  URL: http://localhost:8100  
metadata:
  name: env-config
```

It looks like command to create the ConfigMap is wrong? It's not clear to me why it creates a map with a single key "env-config.yaml".

The YAML file looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
data:
  AWS_BUCKET: mybucket
  AWS_PROFILE: dev
  AWS_REGION: us-east-2
  JWT_SECRET: foo
  POSTGRESS_DB: mydb
  POSTGRESS_HOST: postgreshost
  URL: http://localhost:8100  
metadata:
  name: env-config
  namespace: default
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd say that the issue occurred because you are passing a ConfigMap yaml definition as parameter of `--from-file`.

You could simply create it using:
`kubectl create -f env-config.yaml`

Besides that, if you would like to create using `--from-file`, then you can define your file only with the parameters that you need, it would be something like:

File name: `env-config`

```
AWS_PROFILE: dev
AWS_REGION: us-east-2
JWT_SECRET: foo
POSTGRESS_DB: <mydb>
POSTGRESS_HOST: <my host>
URL: http://localhost:8100
```

And then you can create the ConfigMap in the way you were doing before:

`kubectl create configmap env-config --from-file env-config`

This would create a ConfigMap like that: (`kubectl describe configmap env-config`)

```
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Data
====
env-config:
----
AWS_BUCKET: mybucket
AWS_PROFILE: dev
AWS_REGION: us-east-2
JWT_SECRET: foo
POSTGRESS_DB: <mydb>
POSTGRESS_HOST: <my host>
URL: http://localhost:8100

Events:  <none>
```

Here you can find some useful information:

[Create ConfigMaps from files](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#create-configmaps-from-files)

[Define container environment variables using ConfigMap data](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#define-container-environment-variables-using-configmap-data)

Comment: The distinction between --from-file and --file was lost on me while reading the docs. Thanks for clarifying. I found that "kubectl apply -f ..." worked for me.

Comment: Hey @NateReed would you mind accepting the answer? I think it was pretty complete...

Comment: So is there no way to access the data values that are loaded in this way?

Comment: @alex the way which was used to create the ConfigMap in the question was wrong. If you use the correct way (explained above) you will be able to access the data values.

Comment: This post should be included in the official documentation. Lost so much time

Answer (score 1):

So you kind of got things a little weird. What you have there is a config map with one key named `env-config.yaml`, the value of which is a string containing YAML data for a config map with a bunch of keys including `URL`. I'm guessing you tried using `kubectl create cm --from-file` instead of `kubectl apply -f`?

Comment: I mean the answer is "use kubectl apply -f". I was just explaining how you got to a weird state.

Comment: `kubectl create configmap --from-file` does not mean what you think it means :)

Comment: "kubectl apply -f" worked for me. If you will rephrase your answer as an answer and not a question it will be accepted. :)